# Using fetch instead of jQuery's ajax for a GET API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I recently found myself converting a function that calls a remote API, from returning a callback to returning a `Promise`. I thought that'd be a great opportunity to also replace the `$.ajax` call with a `fetch` call, as `fetch` already returns a `Promise`.

However, this specific call is a `GET` that actually expects a payload (containing key and return type). Specifically, I call it using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: config.serviceUrl,
    data: {
        apiKey: key,
        format: 'json'
    }
})
.done(data => {...})
.fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {...});
```

However, `fetch` does not have a `data` property, and it throws an error if you try to send a `body` with a `GET` request (**`TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body`**). And according to the [Chromium forums](https://codereview.chromium.org/882383002) this is the expected behavior.

Bear in mind: I have absolutely no control of the external API, so mentioning that sending a payload with `GET` violates some API protocol, or suggesting I change the underlying call, is not helpful.

Is it possible to use `fetch` in this scenario? How?

Comment: You can use the `body` property of a fetch request to add data, such as a `FormData` object to the request. Also note that `Fetch` is highly experimental at this stage and not well supported. I'd personally stick with AJAX for now. It would also be helpful if you showed us the actual `Fetch` request you've written

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's `ajax` function simply **appends `data` to the URL as URL parameters** for `GET` requests:

> **data**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

---

Using fetch, you can either do it manually, or you could use an approach similar to that:

```
var url = new URL("http://youapi.com")
var data = {
    apiKey: key,
    format: 'json'
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, data[key]))
fetch(url)
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that all it did was concatenate url params! Great find! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, that method above (`url.searchParams.append`) won't handle nested objects or arrays correctly.

Answer (score 6):

```
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
   fetch(config.serviceUrl + "?apiKey=" + key + "&format=json", 
     {headers:headers, method:"GET"}
   ).then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => /* do stuff with `json` */)
   .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

is equivalent to current `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I was looking for. Wish I could mark both yours and TimoSata's as the right answers.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to abandon this attempt. I keep getting `Unexpected token j in JSON at position 0` on the `response.json()` operation. Since `$.ajax` returns perfectly formed json, I'll just drop fetch. :(

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy What is the response? Can you reproduce syntax error at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co? Have you tried using `response => response.text()` then `.then(text => {json = JSON.parse(text)}` within chained `.then()`?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but no need - I think I solved it: probably me testing so many times caused a 500 error on the server - that still returned a response with the `ok` property set to `true` - so it didn't reject on the fetching, but obviously rejected on the json parsing. While I got that eventually, it still makes me suspect that `fetch` is still not ready for production.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy See documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch _"A fetch() promise rejects with a TypeError when a network error is encountered, although this usually means a permissions issue or similar. An accurate check for a successful fetch() would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the Response.ok property has a value of true. An HTTP status of 404 does not constitute a network error."_. You should be able to test at either of  editors by supplying the `JSON` at `data {json:JSON.stringify(json)}` or `.json` file at plnkr